# Java Creating List of letters from String is not working

Tags: java, list, collections, shuffle

```
String x = "banana";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(x.split(""));
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

When I call the following code, an error appears on the List side of things and tells me to remove the type arguments: String. if I do this then more errors appear. What I am trying to do is shuffle the letters of the word banana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the `List` type is `java.util.List` and not some other type for instance `java.awt.List`

Comment: Although it's a good guess, it's just a guess, and should be a comment, not an answer. It could be some other kind of `List`.

Comment: And it's an answer too :)

Comment: It's a really good guess, and very likely to be the correct answer.  Usually, if you make a guess, and put it in the comment section, somebody else will copy it to the answer section and steal the upvotes when it turns out to be correct.

Comment: Wow that was the solution. So simple